# How do I calculate the size of an entity stored in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there an easy way to calculate the size of an entity stored in App Engine? I would like to know how close a particular entity is to hitting the 1 MB upper limit on entity size.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

App engine stores each entity as a [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).  You can use the `db.model_to_protobuf()` function described [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html#model_to_protobuf) to manually convert your entity into a protobuf and then use the standard `len()` method to determine its size in bytes.

Example usage:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
sz_in_bytes = len(db.model_to_protobuf(some_entity).Encode())
```

---

#### Update for ndb

Kekito points out in the comments below that for `ndb` entities a different approach is needed (Thanks Kekito!):

```
len(some_entity._to_pb().Encode())
```

Comment: The above doesn't seem to work with `ndb` or at least with some `ndb` properties (I'm using a compressed `BlobProperty`), but this does seem to work: `len(some_entity._to_pb().Encode())`

Comment: ...and now `_to_pb` is no longer a method on the ndb `Model` class. This works instead: `from google.cloud.ndb.model import _entity_to_protobuf; _entity_to_protobuf(some_entity)._pb.SerializeToString()`